# feed_PublishTemplatizedAction() returns true, but not posted on my FansPage

Tags: facebook

I need to publish a feed entry to my FansPage. For that I have used the codes as follows,

```
userClient = new FacebookXmlRestClient(api_key, secret);
if(userClient.users_hasAppPermission(Permission.OFFLINE_ACCESS, longFacebookUserID)){
    TemplatizedAction action = new TemplatizedAction("{actor} recommends {book}");                     
    action.setPageActorId(ctProfileId);//fansPageId
    action.addTitleParam("book", "<a href='http://www.amazon.com/Hamlet/dp/0140714545/'>Hamlet</a>");   
    action.setBodyTemplate("{actor} is using BooksApp!");                                               
    action.setBodyGeneral("100 other people recommend this book!");                                     
    action.addPicture("http://code.google.com/hosting/images/code_sm.png", "http://www.google.com"); 
    userClient.feed_PublishTemplatizedAction(action);}
```

When Im executing this code, feed_PublishTemplatizedAction() returns true but not posted on my FansPage.

Can anybody give me the Guidelines.

Thanks,
jerry.

Answer (score 0):

Feed templates have been deprecated and no longer work. You should read up on Feeds / Stream publishing. In addition, you should mode away from the REST API and use the Graph API instead. You app and code appear massively out of date.

You can use the '/me/feed' API call to publish to the users wall.